# Approval WorkFlow error while creating new

Tags: workflow

I am having issue on Sharepoint 2010 approval workflow,below is error message dose not allow me to create new workflow for document liabrary.

Any help on this issue highly appriciated

Thanks

Webpage error details

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1;
>   Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
>   3.0.04506.30; MALC; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) Timestamp: Mon, 25 Feb 2013 15:04:47 UTC
>
> Message: Syntax error Line: 3 Char: 2 Code: 0 URI:
>   /LCeng/_layouts/inc/Core.js?rev=dM%2F1J0wFTiCUw0Zubz9%2BUg%3D%3D
>
> Message: 'BaseControl' is undefined Line: 72 Char: 1 Code: 0 URI:
>   /LCeng/_layouts/FormResource.aspx?solutionId=ADSAHYTP4NWCASFCGSSF6HMNUNZQCCBRGQXDALRQFYYA&view=1&browser=IE8Strict&viewFile=View%2Ejs&version=1
>
> Message: 'UserAgentInfo' is undefined Line: 501 Char: 1 Code: 0 URI:
>   /LCeng/_layouts/CstWrkflIP.aspx?List={9C5E3891-3468-460D-84ED-8DD2152E6325}
>
> Message: 'UserAgentInfo' is undefined Line: 504 Char: 1 Code: 0 URI:
>   /LCeng/_layouts/CstWrkflIP.aspx?List={9C5E3891-3468-460D-84ED-8DD2152E6325}
>
> Message: 'UserAgentInfo' is undefined Line: 507 Char: 1 Code: 0 URI:
>   /LCeng/_layouts/CstWrkflIP.aspx?List={9C5E3891-3468-460D-84ED-8DD2152E6325}
>
> Message: 'CurrentFormData' is undefined Line: 765 Char: 1 Code: 0 URI:
>   /LCeng/_layouts/CstWrkflIP.aspx?List={9C5E3891-3468-460D-84ED-8DD2152E6325}

Comment: Are you using a system account to deploy the workflow?

Comment: yes, i am creating workflow with system account

Comment: Try deploying the workflow using another account that has enough rights but it is not a the system account. The workflows can NOT run if deployed using the system account at least that was my experience.